# How to explicitly set horizontal coordinates when plotting multidimensial Table using DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, csv-format

I'm trying to plot a multidimensial data table which is stored in csv file.

[image]

Like so:

```
DateListPlot[Import["/Users/eljoy/Documents/example.csv"], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

And the output is:

> DateListPlot::dtvals: Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.

```
DateListPlot[{{0.1, 5.27906, 2.47798}, {0.2, 0.081027, 3.40306}, {0.3,
    1.12653, 4.36041}, {0.4, 2.1497, 5.33799}, {0.5, 3.16136, 
    0.0433354}, {0.6, 4.16723, 1.03752}, {0.7, 5.17018, 2.03458}, {0.8,
    6.17167, 3.03309}, {0.9, 0.889232, 4.03235}, {1, 1.88961, 
    5.03197}}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

So obviously I need to explicitly set the horizontal coordinates(which in my turn is the first column). How can I do that?

Comment: `Transpose[]` + explicitly setting a starting date ought to do it: `DateListPlot[Transpose[data], Now]`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you may post this comment as an answer to this question.